# Proof of Total Variance in Statistical Inference

Tags: statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

In book Statistical Inference by Casella, the theorem 4.4.7 (Conditional variance identity), author proves one expectation to be 0 (shown in green rect).

However, I followed the same idea but got different result. I want to know what's wrong with my proof (below).

Thank you!

## My derivation

Consider
\begin{align*}
E_X\big(
\big[ X-E[X|Y] \big] \big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]
\big)
\end{align*}

Note that the expectation is calculated under the distribution of $X$. Also note that $E[X|Y] = g(Y)$ and $EX=\text{constant}$. So we have
\begin{align*}
E_X\big(
\big[ X-E[X|Y] \big] \big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]
\big)
&=
\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]
E_X
\big[ X-E[X|Y] \big] \\
&=
\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]
\big[ EX-E[X|Y] \big] \\
&=
-\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]^2 \\
\end{align*}

I took $\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]$ out because it's a function of $Y$:

$$E_X[h(X) g(Y)] = \int_x [h(X) g(Y)] f_X(x) dx = g(Y) \int_x h(X) f_X(x) dx = g(Y) E_X[h(X)]$$

---

## Statistical Inference by Casella

[image: Theorem 4.4.7 (Conditional variance identity) in Statistical Inference]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]$ is not constant (is some function of $Y$), so how you are able to pull it out the expectation? Also why $E_X \big[ X-E[X|Y] \big] = \big[ EX-E[X|Y] \big] $, shouldn't it be a constant?

Comment: Hi @Esgeriath, I took $\big[ E[X|Y]-EX \big]$ out because it's a function of $Y$: 

$$E_X[h(X) g(Y)] = \int_x [h(X) g(Y)] f_X(x) dx = g(Y) \int_x h(X) f_X(x) dx = g(Y) E_X[h(X)]$$

Comment: @Ben Yeah, I missed it. But the second one still isn't justified. Should be $E_X \big[ X-E[X|Y] \big] =  EX-E\big[E[X|Y] \big] = 0$ I think

Comment: @Esgeriath Thanks! However, no I don't think so. The total expectation is $EX=E_{Y}[E[X|Y]]$, not $EX=E_X[E[X|Y]]$.

Comment: I'm thinking this. For $\text{Var} X$, the author writes:

\begin{align*}
\text{Var} X = 
E \big( \big[ X - EX \big]^2 \big) =
E \big( \big[ X - E(X|Y) + E(X|Y) - EX \big]^2 \big)
\end{align*}

The first $E$ is $E_X$. The second $E$ is not $E_X$, but $E_{X, Y}$ or $E_{X|Y}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking this.

### Step 1

Consider $\text{Var} X$, the author writes:

\begin{align*}
\text{Var} X = 
E \big( \big[ X - EX \big]^2 \big) =
E \big( \big[ X - E(X|Y) + E(X|Y) - EX \big]^2 \big)
\end{align*}

The first $E$ is $E_X$. The second $E$ is not $E_X$, but $E_{X, Y}$.

### Step 2

When we say $EX$, we $E_X X$. However, when we say $E[X-E[X|Y]]$, we actually mean $E_{X, Y}[X-E[X|Y]]$.

To see this, note that $E[X|Y]$ is $g(Y)$, and $X-g(Y)$ is $W$, which is just another random variable.
Taking expectation of $W$, we should expect a number, instead of a function of $Y$. That is, there should not be any randomness.

Think about it in this way. Before, you somehow know X's distribution. So you can calculate $EX$. However, later you realize that X actually depends on Y, and you have a new model/understanding on X, which is: when Y=$y_1$, X has one distribution, and when Y=$y_2$, X has one distribution and so on. Then you can also calculate $EX$, but this time, $EX = E_Y E_{X|Y}[X|Y]$.

Maybe the following notation is clearer:

\begin{align*}
E[X-E[X|Y]] &= E[X-g(Y)] \\
&= E_{X, Y}[X-g(Y)] \\
&= \int_x \int_y (x-g(y)) f_{X, Y}(x, y) dy dx \\
\end{align*}

You can see above we should really consider the joint distribution.

Now,

\begin{align*}
E_{X, Y}[X-g(Y)] 
&= E_Y E_{(X, Y)|Y}[X-g(Y) | Y] \\
&= E_Y E_{X|Y}[X-g(Y) | Y] \\
&= E_Y E_{X|Y}[X-E[X|Y] | Y] \\
&= E_Y \big[
    E_{X|Y}[X|Y]- E[X|Y]
\big] \\
&= 0
\end{align*}